# Do SRAM Macros register the inputs?

Tags: digital-logic, memory, sram, asic

In ASIC design, we often purchase SRAM macros to use in our designs. A typical SRAM macro includes a Verilog description and a timing/layout characterization (lib file).

My question is this: SRAMs always seem to require a clock to operate. Does this mean SRAMs have input registers in them? Or do they have registers at the output, assuming the inputs are registered outside? The figure below shows a simple block diagram of what I am asking.

[image]

Which one is correct?

Comment: If your "macro" doesn't come with a datasheet that spells out details like this explicitly, you should probably look elsewhere.

Comment: I see your point. My question was a bit broad, it does not have to be applicable only to SRAM macros, but any SRAM design in general. In other words, what is the general consensus on this? Your answer implies that it is quite arbitrary to place registers on input/output.

Comment: Exactly. It's completely arbitrary. In fact, from a purely functional perspective, there's no difference at all. The only real difference is how the timing delays are distributed on either side of the register(s). In fact, some synthesis tools are capable of "pushing" registers to different places in a bunch of combinatorial logic in order to optimize timing and/or fanout.

Comment: I see. I came to the same conclusion from my experiments with SRAM blocks. The only difference is in timing. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Most of the times the registers are on the output side, functionally it's the same (except for propagation times). Usually you give the address on on cycle and at the next one the output is stable. All of that is conditional since it really depends on the implementation, it has to be somewhere in the documentation.